# Cannot apply custom color to Menu in Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

As the title says, I have been unable to correctly apply a custom color to a menu in Semantic UI. I have scoured the internet for tutorials, guides, including the Semantic UI page. The only things I have been able to find are people able to successfully apply custom colors to buttons, or people utilizing the default colors defined by Semantic UI for the menu.

```
<div class="ui fluid container">
    <div class="ui segment attached">
        <h1 class="ui header item">CONTERACT</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui fluid container">
    <div class="ui primary attached four item inverted menu">
        <a href="" class="brand item">Project Name</a>
        <a href="" class="active item">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="item">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="item">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have defined the particular color I want as @primaryColor, and this works on a button, just as an experiment, but does not work on the menu. I have also tried to override a default color in site.override with no success. I am under the suspicion that you may not be able to use a custom color with a menu in Semantic UI, but that is also hard to believe considering that defeats the customization aspect.

```
    /**
     User Global Variables
**/
@primaryColor: #fabd42
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for coloured menus can be found [here](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#colored) and from looking at the source code in the examples we can see that to change out a colour a single-use class is used, e.g `red` makes the menu red:

```
<div class="ui red three item menu"></div>
```

And to set `red` as the background colour (instead of text colour) the `inverted` class is added, e.g:

```
<div class="ui red inverted three item menu"></div>
```

That indicates that we need to identify where these single-use colour classes are defined and add our own. Searching the source code via GitHub for [`menu inverted orange`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=menu+inverted+orange&type=) we can find that these are defined in `menu.less` like this:

```
/* Orange */
.ui.inverted.menu .orange.active.item,
.ui.inverted.orange.menu {
  background-color: @orange;
}
.ui.inverted.orange.menu .item:before {
  background-color: @invertedColoredDividerBackground;
}
.ui.inverted.orange.menu .active.item {
  background-color: @invertedColoredActiveBackground !important;
}
```

Therefore to add your own background colour for a menu you need to define a background colour class in the same way, e.g:

```
/* Peach */
.ui.inverted.menu .peach.active.item,
.ui.inverted.peach.menu {
  background-color: @peach;
}
.ui.inverted.peach.menu .item:before {
  background-color: @invertedColoredDividerBackground;
}
.ui.inverted.peach.menu .active.item {
  background-color: @invertedColoredActiveBackground !important;
}
```

Then you need to add the `peach` colour, which can be set in [site.variables](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/themes/material/globals/site.variables#L59), e.g:

```
/*---  Colors  ---*/
@peach            : #FABD42;
```

You're done! You've added your own colour (`peach`) *and* made it available as a background menu colour. The final step is to add the colour class to your menu along with `inverted` to set it as the background colour, e.g:

```
<div class="ui peach inverted primary attached four item menu">

</div>
```

Comment: This same approach works for other semantic-ui elements/collections, such as with table. Using color definition from ```table.less``` and overriding defaults in ```site/collections/table.overrides```  I can define a custom color and add that color to my table. Works also with semantic-ui-react, where I can add ```<Table className="ui newblue"></Table>``` className property where my defined color's name is newblue.